# Angular: Keep the previous value of the observable

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am sending an HTTP request to a backend and receiving the data. I am passing the data through an observable stream and directly subscribing it in my HTML template using async pipe. However, I am having an issue. Since, I want to send multiple requests on the click of the button again and again, I want the observable to keep adding the new values to the data stream instead of entirely replacing the previous ones. How can I do that?

Here's my code:

> TS

```
productsData$ = this.productService.getProduct(this.payload);

loadMore()
{
   ....
   this.productsData$ = this.productService.getProduct(updatedpayload);
}
```

> HTML

```
<div class = "grid" *ngIf="productsData$ | async as productsData">
    <div class="p-col-12 p-md-6 p-lg-3" *ngFor = "let pData of productsData; let i = index">
...
```

How can I retain the previous values in the observable stream while sending an HTTP request and adding the new ones to the existing?

Comment: Try pushing them in to an array every time you get.

Comment: @Chris, I don't want to use an array.

Comment: Was there an issue with my answer? I see that it's no longer accepted

Comment: @eko, unfortunately, it's only rendering one element at a time on the click of a button without displaying any data. I am retrieving with a limit of 3 each time but it's displaying only 1 each time I click on the button.

Comment: what do you mean by without displaying any data? maybe the format is wrong? can you put some console.logs to the tap? `tap((product)=> {
   console.log(product)
    this.previousProductsData.push(product)
  }),`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with the comments. You can create a cache array and leverage that to return the previous values as well.

```js
private readonly previousProductsData = [];

readonly buttonTrigger$ = new BehaviourSubject('');

productsData$ = this.buttonTrigger$.pipe(
  switchMap(()=> this.productService.getProduct(this.payload)),
  tap((product)=> {
    this.previousProductsData.push(product)
  }),
  map(()=> this.previousProductsData)
);
```

and the button click could look like:

```js
loadMore()
{
   ....
  this.productService.buttonTrigger$.next('');
}
```

Comment: In this example introduction of buttonTrigger$ Observable makes no sense as it immediately  switches to http call.

Comment: @LukaszGawrys I'm using that to listen to the "load more" button clicks. So with each button click, it will trigger the api to get more products, push the result to the cache and return the cached result. Of course you can create a separate observable for the product and use `combineLatest` to join them but this is simpler IMO.

Comment: @eko, I have accepted this answer as correct but, the solution was not working for me properly. I declared an additional observable and ended up using concat to merge the two. Since, I was subscribing in my template using async pipe so, this worked for me. Thanks for your time, though. :)

Comment: You can/should provide a new answer and self accept that but glad you figured it out :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try [merge](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/merge) from rxjs

```
productsData$ = this.productService.getProduct(this.payload);

loadMore(){
  ....
  this.productsData$ = merge(this.productsData$, this.productService.getProduct(updatedpayload));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

push the response to an array and use that to display

```
this.productsData$ = this.productService.getProduct(updatedpayload);
this.productArray.push(this.productsData$);
```

And display productArray

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use `BehaviorSubject` for this problem but a bit differently than the accepted answer proposed.

First of all I would put all the data handling logic into the service and not the component consuming it.

```
  private productsDataSubject: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject([]);
  public productsData$ = this.productsDataSubject.asObservable();

  getProduct(payload: any) {
    return this.httpClient.get('xxx').pipe(
      tap((product) => {
        this.productsDataSubject.next([...this.productsDataSubject.getValue(), product]);
      }),
    )
  }
```

In the component we then only have this

```
  public productsData$ = this.productService.productsData$;

  loadMore(){
    // plain http observable doesn't have to be unsubscribed so it's ok to leave it here
    this.productService.getProduct(this.payload).subscribe();
  }
```

It would be better for reusing it and combining with other data streams.